# Magento 2: SQL Query to get product SKU's based on the Category Id

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, sql

I need a sql query to get the all sku based on the category id

Following are the tables which stores category and product data:

> catalog_product_entity

> catalog_category_product

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT product.entity_id as product_id, product.sku FROM catalog_product_entity as product
    INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as cat_prod on product.entity_id = cat_prod.product_id
    WHERE cat_prod.category_id=YOUR Category ID;
```

Tried using inner join,this one also worked

Answer (score 5):

Your Sql query will be like this:

```
`SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity where entity_id in (SELECT product_id FROM catalog_category_product where category_id = {YourCategoryId})`.
```